# C++/CLI Changing encoding

Tags: utf-8, c++-cli, ascii

Good Day,
I've been writing a simple program using the Windows API, it's written in C++/CLI.
The problem I've encountered is, I'm loading a library (`.dll`) and then calling its functions. one of the functions returns char*. So I add the returned value to my textbox

```
output->Text = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi
                   (IntPtr(Function()));
```

Now, as you can see this is encoded in ANSI, the char* returned is, I presume, also ANSI (or Windows-1252, w/e you guys call it :>). The original data, which the function in LIBRARY gets is encoded in UTF-8, variable-length byte field, terminated by 0x00.  There are a lot of non-Latin characters in my program, so this is troubling. I've also tried this

```
USES_CONVERSION;
wchar_t* pUnicodeString = 0;
pUnicodeString = A2W( Function());

output->Text = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringUni
                   (IntPtr(pUnicodeString));
```

using `atlconv.h`. It still prints malformed/wrong characters. So my question would be, can I convert it to something like UTF-8 so I would be able to see correct output, or does the char* loose the necessary information required to do so? Maybe changing the .dll source code would help, but it's quite old and written in C, so i don't want to mess with it :/ 
I hope the information I provided was sufficient, if you need anything more, just ask.

Comment: You're second snippet has more hope.  You have to pass pUnicodeString to PtrTostringUni() though.

Comment: I forgot: you can't use A2W(), it doesn't do utf-8 decoding.  Use MultiByteToWideChar() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no standard way to handle UTF-8. Try to google appropriate converters, e.g. http://www.nuclex.org/articles/cxx/10-marshaling-strings-in-cxx-cli , [Convert from C++/CLI pointer to native C++ pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271022/convert-from-c-cli-pointer-to-native-c-pointer) .

Also, your second code snippet doesn't use pUnicodeString, it doesn't look right.

Comment: I'm sorry, i misstyped the second code, it should be output->Text = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringUni(IntPtr(pUnicodeString)); The fact doesn't change though, it's not working :( (I've fixed the original post.)

Comment: Have you tried `System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetString(bytes)` from the link above?

Comment: How would I use System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetString(bytes) with char*?

Comment: Have you opened the link?! // Copy the C++ string contents into a managed array of bytes
array<unsigned char> ^bytes = gcnew array<unsigned char>(byteCount);
{ pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinnedBytes = &bytes[0];
memcpy(pinnedBytes, cxxString.c_str(), byteCount);
}

Comment: Thank you guys, it's working lovely, sorry for not noticing it kan :), thank you.